# Is it possible to change owner of SP in Crystal reports at runtime?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'd like to change the owner of stored procedure (i.e. dbo) for smth else in crystal reports at runtime. Is it possible?
TIA

**UDP**
May be I need to clarify. I have a reports with lots of subreport within. I have to use this report with the other database. So I need to change the scheme of stored procedure at runtime without changing anything at DB.

Should I use `SetDataSource()` method or is there smth else more corresponding changing scheme task?

Comment: as owner you mean the connection to the DB?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired effect without changing the owner using the [EXECUTE AS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx) Clause.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestProcedure
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
```

There are basically five types of impersonation that can be used:

- SELF - the specified user is the person creating or altering the module
- CALLER - this will take on the permissions of the current user
- OWNER - this will take on the permissions of the owner of the module being called
- 'user_name' - a specific user
- 'login_name' - a specific login

See Sommarskog's canonical reference: [Giving Permissions through Stored Procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html#EXECUTE_AS)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question, you can use the sp_changeobjectowner  system sproc to change the owner of an object in the database.